# Azure hybrid VM verification

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, verification, hybrid

I am working on a new project and testing out the Azure Vm. I noticed that i cna activate azure hybrid while creating the Vm or on an existing one. i have done that but i dont understand how? wont Microsoft ask me to at least key in the license i am suppose to have? is there any action to verify?

also another question is, if i have 1 server or client license and i have 2 VM of the same type ( both servers or client win10) would the same license work on each or only on one VM?

i have tried looking into MS community but i dont think anyone is asking a similar question.

Comment: Can you share the steps you followed?

Comment: i just switched the button on. 
In azure portal -> Vm -> configuration -> switched the button on, tick on i have a windows license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Azure Hybrid Benefit FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/hybrid-benefit/faq/#:%7E:text=The%20Azure%20Hybrid%20Benefit%20for%20Standard%20Edition%20licenses,to%20individual%20VMs%20or%20to%20the%20entire%20host.).

*How do I activate the Azure Hybrid Benefit for Windows Server?*

> To use Windows virtual machines with the Azure Hybrid Benefit, do one
> of the following.
>
> - Deploy VMs from one of the Windows Server images provided on the Azure Marketplace.
> - Upload a custom VM and deploy using a Resource Manager template or Azure PowerShell.
> - Convert existing VM in Azure to the Azure Hybrid Benefit cost for Windows Server.
> - Apply Azure Hybrid Benefit for Windows Server on virtual machine scale set as well.
>
> [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/hybrid-use-benefit-licensing).

If you create a VM with Azure Hybrid Benefit for Windows Server via Azure portal, use the toggle under the **Save money** section.

*[How to verify your VM is utilizing the licensing benefit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/hybrid-use-benefit-licensing#how-to-verify-your-vm-is-utilizing-the-licensing-benefit)*

The following PowerShell example shows the license type for a single VM.

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroup "myResourceGroup" -Name "myVM"
```

**Output:**

```
Copy
Type                     : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
Location                 : westus
LicenseType              : Windows_Server
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: i have done that. but how would Azure verify that i do have the license? lets say i made a new Vm and i apply azure benefits to that Vm. is it applied without any verifying that i do have License? sadly i cant find an answer to that on the hybrid FAQ.

Comment: I see. from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/azure-hybrid-benefit#how-to-maintain-compliance) `Microsoft reserves the right to audit end customer at any time to verify eligibility for Azure Hybrid Benefit utilization.` From [this blog](https://petri.com/hybrid-use-benefit-reduces-azure-vm-costs),To avail of HUB/AHB, you must acquire Windows Server in one of two ways: 1.Purchase/subscribe to Windows Server with Software Assurance (SA).2.Subscribe to Windows Server through the very new option of Cloud Solution Provider subscriptions.

Comment: In my view, when you activate your windows server, it might be verified Windows Server with Software Assurance (SA).

Comment: Probably, MS trusts everyone who enables the hybrid benefits without verifying the License. There are no clues on Googles but contact MS support.

Comment: I agree with you. Google didnt take me anywhere and MS support is kind of slow but i think based on your comment from the document, they should ask to verify it sooner or later. 
Thank you very much ^^.